# $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}$ for $x_i \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=1$

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x_1,\dots, x_n\in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=1$. Prove that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}
> $$

I tried using *AM-GM* and *Cauchy-Schwarz* but didn't come to anything useful.
Hint could be an help too.

Please advise.

Comment: Think *convex* …

Comment: Did not try yet, but do you know Jensen inequality?

Comment: Apparently several solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx_i%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x_i%7D%7D%7D%20%5Cgeq%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bn-1%7D%7D%24

Comment: There is one solution on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881457/prove-sum-n-i-1-fracx-i-sqrt1-x-i-geq-frac1-sqrtn-1-sum-n-i) as well...

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600259/42969

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz (without "t") cannot work because the inequality sign is not the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x/\sqrt{1-x}$ is convex on $(-1,1)$, so by Jensen's inequality, one has
\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{x_{i}}{\sqrt{1-x_{i}}}\geq \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n}x_{i}}{\sqrt{1-\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n}x_{i}}}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} =\sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{1-(1-x_i)}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}}=\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}}-\sum_{i=1}^n{\sqrt{1-x_i}}
$$

Using *Cauchy-Schwarz*,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\sqrt{1-x_i}}\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{(1-x_i)}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n{1}}=\sqrt{(n-1)n}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} \ge \frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{1}\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{(n-1)n}}
$$

therefore
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1-x_i}}} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{(n-1)n}} -\sqrt{(n-1)n} = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}
$$